# Java - xml list or one value

Tags: java, xml

What I have to do to check I have got list of data or one argument?

I have got this in code software and he show "yes" if argument 1 but if I have got list I have got empty place. I would like to make If which can accept only one agument but no list.

```
System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getNodeName());    
System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getLastChild().getNodeValue());
```

Output (because car have list of nodes and If some element have list not one value I don`t want to show this element for example "car"):

```
Adam
yes
car
```

List:

```
<car>
<window>yes</window>
<door>yes</door>
</car>
```

1 argument

```
<Adam>yes</Adam>
```

Comment: I can't even tell what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and tell us exactly what you're trying to do and what problem you're facing. The way it stands right now, I don't think anyone can decipher what your requirements are

Comment: @Sam I am Editet once again. Now I hope is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the length of the list.

And you probably don't want all kinds of child nodes, rather just child elements. Try

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("*")
```

instead.

Comment: I check and all the time is problem. doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().length()

Comment: I can`t using Tag name because I never know how will look like my xml tree -> but I start thinking one more time about lenght and now is working -> if(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getChildNodes().getLength() >=1)